# How to include files in a subdirectory of a CMake project, without using another CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, c, cmake, git-submodules

I have a project added as a submodule to another project using CMake. The submodule is just two files (`b.c`, `b.h`) so the project structure is:

```
root/
 | CMakeLists.txt
 | main.cc
 | a.cc
 | a.h
 | submodule/
 |   |  b.c
 |   |  b.h
```

I don't want to add another CMakeLists.txt to the submodule as it's just another git thing to maintain. The submodule will never grow beyond these two files so I just want something simple and CMake is overkill for some of my other projects, so I don't want it in the submodule's git repo.

If I try `include_directories(submodule)` and add `submodule/b.c` to the sources list of my `add_executable` block, I get undefined references to the functions inside `b.c/h`

Is there a quick and simple way to just add these extra files to the sources without getting undefined references? Or is there a better way of managing this tiny library?

I have

```
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/submodule)

...

add_executable(${NAME}
    submodule/b.c
    main.cpp
    server.cc
)
```

I have also tried adding

```
target_link_directories(${NAME} PUBLIC 
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/submodule
)
```

The error is:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/light.dir/
server.cc.obj: in function `tcpRecvCallback(void*, tcp_pcb*, pbuf*, signed char) [clon
e .part.0]':
server.cc:(.text._Z15tcpRecvCallbackPvP7tcp_pcbP4pbufa.part.0+0x62): undefined referen
ce to `http_req_parse(char*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/light.dir/build.make:3083: light.elf] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1520: CMakeFiles/light.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:156: all] Error 2
```

where server.cc is in the project root, and `http_req_parse` is a function in `b.c`

`main.cpp` includes `server.h` which includes `submodule/b.h`

It may be relevant that I am building for a raspberry pi pico W.

Comment: To use include_directories you need a full path, for example: `include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/submodule)`

Comment: Specifying `submodule/b.c` among source files for your executable should eliminate "undefined reference" error. If the error persist, then something wrong with your **C/C++ code**, and without that code (and without the **exact error message**) we cannot help you. Please, add these things into your question post. Note also, that we don't want your *production* code but [mcve] instead.

Comment: I have updated with the error message and explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new answer:

```
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/submodule)

set(SOURCES submodule/b.c)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} SOURCES)
```

old answer:

```
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/submodule)

file(GLOB submodule_source submodule/*.c)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} submodule_source)
```

Comment: I have tried this but unfortunately it did not help

Comment: @confusedandsad you can try the answer i modified

Comment: Instead of using the file globs I just list the files in the sources list since there are only two. Is that ok? It still does not build either way unfortunately.

Comment: @confusedandsad try the new answer

Comment: I believe I have equivalent, have updated question to show it

Comment: Typo: CMake doesn't use commas to separate argument.

Comment: @Lindydancer yes, I modified it

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that all the above answers were correct, I had forgotten to use the language specific guards, since my library was in C, and my project was in C++.

IE, I didn't have

```
#ifdef _cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```